# Reason behind <apex:inputText> element value must resolve to a String type!

Tags: visualforce

I faced an issue with `<apex:inputText>` while using disabled attribute with it.

The scenario is i can disable and enable the `<apex:inputText>` using a checkbox.

`<apex:inputText>` is binded with an Integer variable.

But when i enable the

```
<apex:inputText>
```

i get error : **element value must resolve to a String type!**

I tried these workarounds given in this post 
[apex:inputText disabled binding causing "element value must resolve to a String type!"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13871/apexinputtext-disabled-binding-causing-element-value-must-resolve-to-a-string)

But the above workarounds changes the appearance , the goal is not achievable.

When i tried binding `<apex:inputText>` with String , the functionality worked fine , however now i have to make use of Integer.valueOf(myStringVariable) everywhere i need to do calculations in my code.

I just want to know the reason behind this error **element value must resolve to a String type!**

Why this doesn't work with integer value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in Visualforce - its been around since 2008 by the look of this post on the Developerforce Discussion Boards:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000951yIAA

The best I've been able to do with this is to have the underlying property still stored as an Integer, but have a string based getter/setter for it that converts to/from a string.  That way I can use the property as an Integer within my code and I just have to convert it once.

You'll need an answer from Salesforce as to why it works this way - given that people have been complaining about this behaviour for nearly 6 years, it feels like they might think its working correctly. Although Doug Chasman does suggest its a bug in the developerforce post above.

Comment: hit this today. Seems as long as the property uses `{get;set}` and is not assigned a value in the controller you are fine. But as soon as you do say `prop = 1` like in the constructor the error is thrown. Wierd how empty getter and setter work but assign a number to it and bam, broke

Answer (score 0):

BTW, `immediate="true"` fix this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use outputText instead of disabled:

```
<apex:outputText id="test1" value="{!item.Number}" rendered="{!item.isallowed}"/>
```

This worked for me. Hope this is helpful.